# AngularJS Weird Behavior, NG-INCLUDE Causes Whole Page to Re-Load

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

A simple `ng-include` causes the page to recursively print out the whole site over and over in an area of the page, this causes the browser to crash. If I change the path the same thing happens so apparently it's not even looking at the path. If i use `ng-include` anywhere on the page the same weird behavior will happen.

The template (list.html) is in a sub-folder to where the angularjs scripts are.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-if="comments_data">

    <div ng-include="'templates/list.html'"></div>
</div>
```

**Template**

```
<li ng-repeat="comment in comments_data">
    {{ print_some_stuff }}
</li>
```

Comment: I would try replacing the ng-include with a Directive.

Comment: This works fine for me. The issue may be with the structure of the comments_data, since the iteration is infinite and crashing the browser

Comment: @Coldstar it doesn't have to do with comment_data because if I place the include directive with a path to an nonexistent template it still crashes.

Comment: without see a complete code sample, with angular initializations, I cant put a finger on the issue. Other than that it works fine on my end

Comment: @user3704920 - Did you ever figure out what's going on here? I'm seeing the same thing... but only on prod, stage and dev work fine...

Comment: @MattGrande I did not. Angular would fight me every step of the way to do anything so I went the knockoutjs way.

Answer (score 2):

Can you please try:

```
<div ng-if="comments_data">
    <div ng-include="'/templates/list.html'"></div>
</div>
```

The slash at the beginning of the path was the issue for me. Check your router and see how templates are loaded (should be the same way with a leading slash).

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if this will be useful.

```
<div ng-include="'templates/list.html'" ng-controller="CommentsController" ng-show="isCommentAvailable()"></div>

.controller('CommentsController', function() {
    $scope.comments_data;

    $scope.isCommentAvailable = function() {
        if ($scope.comments_data)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: that actually crashed it with no results.